# XML Oracle : Multiple Child Node extract

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

I have an xml code :

```
<begin>
    <entry>
        <lastname>gordon</lastname>
        <NumberList>
            <number>100</number>
            <codelist>
                 <code>213</code>
                 <code>214</code>
            <codelist>
            <login>
                 <user>user1</user>
                 <user>user2</user>
            </login>
        <NumberList>
        <address>
            <addresslist>Jl. jalan pelan-pelan ke Bekasi, Indonesia</addresslist>
        </address>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <lastname>mark</lastname>
        <address>
            <addresslist>Jl. jalan cepet-cepet ke Jakarta, Indonesia</addresslist>
        </address>
    </entry>
</begin>
```

my code:

```
FOR r IN (SELECT VALUE(p) col_val,
                 EXTRACT(VALUE(P), '/entry/codelist') AS code,
                 EXTRACT(VALUE(P), '/entry/login') AS login
           FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/begin/entry'))) p)
LOOP
   IF r.col_val.existsnode('/entry/lastname/text()') > 0 
   THEN
      vc_lastname := r.col_val.extract('/sdnEntry/lastname/text()').getstringval();
   END IF;

   IF r.col_val.existsnode('/entry/address/addresslist/text()') > 0 
   THEN
    vc_address := r.col_val.extract('/sdnEntry/address/addresslist/text()').getstringval();
   END IF;

   IF r.col_val.existsnode('/entry/codelist/id/code/text()') > 0 AND r.col_val.existsnode('/entry/login/user/text()') > 0 
   THEN
      FOR R1 IN (SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(T1), '/codelist/code/text()') AS code
                   FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(R.code, '/codelist'))) T1)
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vc_uid||' - '||vc_firstName||' - '||R1.code||' - '||R2.address);
      END LOOP;

      FOR R2 IN (SELECT
                        EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(T1), '/login/user/text()') AS user
                   FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(R.address, 'login/'))) T1)
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vc_uid||' - '||vc_firstName||' - '||R2.user||' - '||R2.address);
      END LOOP;
  ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vc_uid||' - '||vc_firstName);
  END IF;
```

My problem : How to loop child nodes so the data will become like this :

```
LastName | Number | code    | user  |   address
gordon   | 100    | 213     | user1 |Jl. jalan pelan-pelan ke Bekasi, Indonesia
gordon   | 100    | 213     | user2 |Jl. jalan pelan-pelan ke Bekasi, Indonesia
gordon   | 100    | 214     | user1 |Jl. jalan pelan-pelan ke Bekasi, Indonesia
gordon   | 100    | 214     | user2 |Jl. jalan pelan-pelan ke Bekasi, Indonesia
mark     | Null   | null    | null  |Jl. jalan cepet-cepet ke Jakarta, Indonesia
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle XML : Skip Not exist Node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583872/oracle-xml-skip-not-exist-node)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve desired result by using `XMLTable()` function:

```
select q.Lastname
     , q.Numberid
     , s.codeid
     , w.LoginId
     , q.address
  from t1 t
  left join xmltable('/begin/entry'
                      passing t.xml_col 
                      columns LastName   varchar2(21)  path 'lastname',
                              NumberId   number        path 'NumberList/number',
                              Address    varchar2(201) path 'address/addresslist',
                              CodeList   XmlType       Path 'NumberList/codelist/code',
                              Logins     XmlType       Path 'NumberList/login/user'
                      ) q
    on (1=1) 
  left join xmltable('/code'
                      passing q.CodeList
                      columns CodeId number path '.') s
    on (1=1)
  left join   xmltable('/user'
                        passing q.Logins
                        columns LoginId varchar2(11) path '.') w
    on (1=1)
```

Result: [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/522a1/1)

```
Lastname Numberid Codeid Loginid Address 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gordon   100      213    user1   Jl. jalan pelan-pelan ke Bekasi, Indonesia 
gordon   100      213    user2   Jl. jalan pelan-pelan ke Bekasi, Indonesia 
gordon   100      214    user1   Jl. jalan pelan-pelan ke Bekasi, Indonesia 
gordon   100      214    user2   Jl. jalan pelan-pelan ke Bekasi, Indonesia 
mark     null     null   null    Jl. jalan cepet-cepet ke Jakarta, Indonesia
```

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_xquery.htm#sthref1404) about `XMLTable()` function.

**Note**: Working with Oracle releases prior to 11.2.0.2, you can encounter `ORA-1780 error`(bug 8545377) on certain types of XML queries when `cursor_sharing` parameter is set to `FORCE` or `SIMILAR`(deprecated starting from 11.2). Setting `cursor_sharing` parameter to `EXACT`(default value), will solve the problem.

Comment: great!!.. helpful for me.

Comment: why is it raising `ORA-01780: string literal required` error if I did not set `alter session set cursor_sharing = exact;' ?? Im using 11g

Comment: ok thanks for the info !! hope you meant sharing instead of shearing

Comment: wow its working!! thx very much !! i'm using 10g anyway no prob with codes above

Comment: I apologize for injecting [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857964/oracle-parsing-xml-returns-blank) here but I'm trying to use your solution to my problem and it's giving me blank results. In my case, `t1.xml_col` is of type `NCLOB` if that helps.