# Oracle extract XML data from clob fails

Tags: xml, oracle, clob

I am using oracle version 11.2.0.4.0 
I have a table FINMESSAGES with a CLOB column, columnname MESSAGE
I want to extract an xml-element from the MESSAGE column and I did this 
with the following code 
(according to a solution in found here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589276/xml-oracle-multiple-child-node-extract))

```
SELECT
   x.*

FROM

   FINMESSAGES FM
   left join XMLTable(
   '/masterData'
   passing FM.MESSAGE
   columns
   latestversion varchar2(6) path 'version'
   )  x on (1=1)
;
```

but I got the following error :

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 818 Column: 12
```

Who knows what I do wrong ? 
thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
   x.*    
FROM

   FINMESSAGES FM
   left join XMLTable(
   '/masterData'
   passing XMLPARSE(CONTENT FM.MESSAGE WELLFORMED)
   columns
   latestversion varchar2(6) path 'version'
   )  x on (1=1)
;
```

or `XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT FM.MESSAGE WELLFORMED)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the CLOB value to an XMLType first by using the XMLTYPE.createxml() function.
Replace **passing FM.MESSAGE** with **passing XMLTYPE.createxml(FM.MESSAGE)**.

Here is my testcase:

```
create table xmltest 
( a number, b clob );

insert into xmltest values ( 1, '<masterData>asd</masterData>' );
insert into xmltest values ( 2, '<masterData><version>asd</version></masterData>' );
commit;

select XMLTYPE.createxml( b ) from xmltest;

SELECT
   x.*
FROM
   xmltest FM
   left join XMLTable(
   '/masterData'
   passing XMLTYPE.createxml( fm.b )
   columns
   latestversion varchar2(6) path 'version'
   )  x on (1=1)
;
```

Here is some documentation:

[XMLTABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions240.htm)

[XMLTYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71959)