# convert XML to table in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, extract

I have a XML in the below format, store in column of XMLType in oracle database

```
<a>
<c>1</c>
<c>2</c>
</a>
```

I need to convert this in table format as

```
c
1
2
```

Any idea how to do this using SQL?

Answer (score 3):

```
with data as
(select '<a><c>1</c><c>2</c></a>' xmlval
 from dual)
( select c
  from data d, 
       xmltable('/a/*' passing xmltype(d.xmlval) 
        columns
    c varchar2(254) path '/c'   
))
```

Comment: Thanks for solution Frank. I had almost figured it out except for the fact using "*" in '/a/*'

Answer (score 0):

There is answer in this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982687/oracle-plsql-how-to-parse-xml-and-insert-into-table).

For instance user daggett did this:

```
select *  
FROM XMLTABLE('/person/row'  
         PASSING   
            xmltype('
                <person>
                   <row>
                       <name>Tom</name>
                       <Address>
                           <State>California</State>
                           <City>Los angeles</City>
                       </Address>
                   </row>
                   <row>
                       <name>Jim</name>
                       <Address>
                           <State>California</State>
                           <City>Los angeles</City>
                       </Address>
                   </row>
                </person>
            ')
         COLUMNS  
            --describe columns and path to them:  
            name  varchar2(20)    PATH './name',  
            state varchar2(20)    PATH './Address/State',  
            city  varchar2(20)    PATH './Address/City'
     ) xmlt  
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it's work.

pISLEMLER CLOB;

```
    select *  
    FROM XMLTABLE('/mydata/UCRET'  
             PASSING   
                xmltype('<mydata>'||pISLEMLER||'</mydata>
                ')
             COLUMNS  
                --describe columns and path to them:  
                F_M_IS_ID  varchar2(20)    PATH './FMISID',  
                ISKONTO varchar2(20)    PATH 'ISK'
         ) xmlt;
```