# ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I can successfully read from xml definition which has only one node. But when I am trying to read multiple node from xml definition I get the following error -

> ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node.

Below is my xml definition

```html
<form xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner" fr:data-format-version="4.0.0">
    <applicant>
        <userId>1234</userId>
        <userName>Dan Johnson</userName>
        <userEmail>johnson.dan@test.com</userEmail>                                            
    </applicant>       
    <background>
        <additionalDuties>Nothing</additionalDuties>
           <grid-7>
            <position>Service desk analyst</position>
            <workplace>Chicago</workplace>
            <date>1234</date>
            <duties>NA</duties>
           </grid-7>
           <grid-7>
             <position>Service desk analyst 1</position>
             <workplace>New york</workplace>
             <date>123123</date>
             <duties>NA</duties>
           </grid-7>
    </background>
</form>
```

SQL query

```sql
SELECT extractvalue(xml, '//*/userId/text()') AS "E-number",
       extractvalue(xml, '//*/userName/text()') AS "Name",
       extractvalue(xml, '//*/userEmail/text()') AS "Email",
       extractvalue(xml, '//*/additionalDuties/text()') AS "Responsibilities",
       extractvalue(xml, '//*/position/text()') AS "Position",
       extractvalue(xml, '//*/workplace/text()') AS "Workplace",
       extractvalue(xml, '//*/date/text()') AS "Date",
       extractvalue(xml, '//*/duties/text()') AS "Duties"
  FROM form_data fd
 WHERE form = 'form-name'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert XML to table in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670061/convert-xml-to-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html#GUID-C4A32C58-33E5-4CF1-A1FE-039550D3ECFA) which is recommended by Oracle rather than deprecated function `EXTRACTVALUE` such as

```sql
WITH form_data( xml ) AS
(
 SELECT XMLType(
          REPLACE(
                  '<form xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner" fr:data-format-version="4.0.0">
                         the rest of your XML is embedded here
                   </form>','grid-','grid')
          )
   FROM dual
)
SELECT "E-number", "Name", "Email", "Responsibilities", 
       "Position", "Workplace","Date","Duties"
  FROM form_data,
  XMLTABLE('/form/applicant'
      PASSING xml
      COLUMNS 
             "E-number" VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'userId',
             "Name"     VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'userName',
             "Email"    VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'userEmail'
         ),
  XMLTABLE('/form/background/grid7'
      PASSING xml
      COLUMNS          
             "Responsibilities" VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'duties',
             "Position"         VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'position',
             "Workplace"        VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'workplace',
             "Date"             VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'date',
             "Duties"           VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'duties' 
         )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6be6600a99aafd89b961827b56aa7888)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMLTABLE`:

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/form/background/grid-7'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(xml)
         COLUMNS
           "E-number"         NUMBER        PATH './../../applicant/userId',     
           "Name"             VARCHAR2(150) PATH './../../applicant/userName',
           "Email"            VARCHAR2(150) PATH './../../applicant/userEmail',
           "Responsibilities" VARCHAR2(150) PATH './../additionalDuties',
           "Position"         VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'position',
           "Workplace"        VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'workplace',
           "Date"             NUMBER        PATH 'date',
           "Duties"           VARCHAR2(150) PATH 'duties' 
        ) x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (xml) AS
SELECT TO_CLOB('<form xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner" fr:data-format-version="4.0.0">
    <applicant>
        <userId>1234</userId>
        <userName>Dan Johnson</userName>
        <userEmail>johnson.dan@test.com</userEmail>                                            
    </applicant>       
    <background>
        <additionalDuties>Nothing</additionalDuties>
        <grid-7>
            <position>Service desk analyst</position>
            <workplace>Chicago</workplace>
            <date>1234</date>
            <duties>NA</duties>
        </grid-7>
        <grid-7>
             <position>Service desk analyst 1</position>
             <workplace>New york</workplace>
             <date>123123</date>
             <duties>NA</duties>
        </grid-7>
    </background>
</form>') FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | E-number | Name | Email | Responsibilities | Position | Workplace | Date | Duties |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1234 | Dan Johnson | johnson.dan@test.com | Nothing | Service desk analyst | Chicago | 1234 | NA |
> | 1234 | Dan Johnson | johnson.dan@test.com | Nothing | Service desk analyst 1 | New york | 123123 | NA |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5551809ab1b5379141d896eaf93795ad)*