# Oracle Procedure to accept multi row input from front end application

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write a procedure which accepts multiple records with multi rows record set from web portal. Please let me know how can I implement it? 
What's the best way to send the multi row data from portal and how to accept it in a procedure?

Ex:

Around 30 fields are single set of data and each these records set contains minimum 3 set of other records.

```
F1: THEJ   F2: KUMAR  F3: 30/4/1990  F4: IND  F5: DWA  F6: 8789765678   
---- etc up to thirty fields F30: XXX
```

And each these single set contains multiple rows like below

```
R1           R2              R3            R4                R5           
DD1          2               RAI           20/2/2010         DD          
DD2          1               RAN           20/3/2010         DD1          
DD3          0               THU           20/4/2010         DD2
```

Comment: Presumably, you want the procedure to accept a collection of some type.  There are multiple types of collections in PL/SQL.  Which one you use will, among other things, strongly be influenced by what sort of collection your middle tier is capable of passing in.

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you for the information. If I declare input parameter as collection type then  how the data should be from web portal? is it can send the data in a table type from portal? Note: here we are not using any middle layer. Its a direct call from web portal.

Comment: Your "web portal" is, presumably, a middle tier.  It's running Java/ .NET/ PHP/ Python/ etc.-- something other than PL/SQL using some sort of API to interact with the database.  What sort of collection that API is capable of passing in will determine what sort of collection your procedure should accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a well-defined XML data from the front-end and pass to an Oracle SP as string. With in the SP, you may parse the xml to read the all incoming values.

You may make use of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982687/oracle-plsql-how-to-parse-xml-and-insert-into-table) question/answer to fit your req'mt

Comment: Thank you Aishu.. Is there any other way of doing it? other than XML Parsing.